# need to prove that the determinant of the inverse of a matrix is equal to 1 over the determinant of that matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

I need to do some practice exercices and I am struggling with this one.
A and B, inversible square matrixes
prove that the determinant of an inverted matrix is equal to 1 over that matrix

|A^-1| = 1/|A|

(edit) im a french speaker from canada so I have a hard time using the english terms correctly since I use them in french normally. excuse me if there are any syntax/usage errors

Comment: *Hint*: The determinant is multiplicative.

Comment: Hi, poor English is not the real problem here. We can all infer that by *inversible* you mean *invertible* and so on (though one may consider spell-checking browser extension). But you should elaborate on the question. What have you tried, what you think might be the way to prove it. Also, we need to know your level of understanding of linear algebra. For example, when I was writing my answer, I didn't know your level of understanding. So I don't know what exactly you want to explain.

Comment: Also, why do you assume *B* is invertible? There is no matrix *B* in the question. This surplus assumption is a kind of baggage that makes it look like you don't think much about the question, i.e. makes it look like that it is not a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By multiplicativity of determinant: $|A||A^{-1}|=|A\cdot A^{-1}|=|Id|=1$, where by $Id$   I mean identity matrix.

From this, we can *almost* conclude that $|A^{-1}|=1/|A|$. The only thing that we need to check, is that we *can* divide by $|A|$. In other words, we need to make sure that $|A|$ is not zero.

But we know $A$ is invertible ( or equivalently regular/having full rank), hence the determinant is non-zero.

Comment: thank you very much!